# На сервере не отображается ответ при калькуляции

Tags: java, servlet

После запуска программы( тестовый образец калькулятора) не выводится результат. Строка Result: ${requestScope.result} - не меняется, хотя вместо ${requestScope.result} должен выводиться результат.  В это же время - консоль в intellij idea ответ выводит. То есть, при нажатии кнопки "calculate" на сервере изменений нет, а консоль выводит правильный ответ. При делении на ноль - сервер выводит прописанное в методе сообщение "You cannot divide by zero". В чем может быть проблема?
Мой Сервлет:

```
import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/calculate")
public class CalculatorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("calculatorServlet.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer;
        writer = resp.getWriter();
        String operation = req.getParameter("operation");
        double firstOperand = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("firstOperand"));
        double secondOperand = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("secondOperand"));
        double result;
        switch (operation) {
            case "add":
                result = firstOperand + secondOperand;
                break;
            case "subtraction":
                result = firstOperand - secondOperand;
                break;
            case "multiply":
                result = firstOperand * secondOperand;
                break;
            case "divide":
                if (secondOperand != 0) {
                    result = firstOperand / secondOperand;
                } else {
                    writer.println("You cannot divide by zero");
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                writer.println("I don't know its operation!");
                return;
        }
        req.setAttribute("result", result);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/calculatorServlet.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

мой jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculate Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculate Page</h1>
<form action="calculate" method="post">
<label for="firstOperand">Enter number 1: </label>
<input type="text" id="firstOperand" name="firstOperand" required>
<label for="operation">Choose operation: </label>
<select id="operation" name="operation">
<option value="add">Addition</option>
<option value="subtraction">Subtraction</option>
<option value="multiply">Multiplication</option>
<option value="divide">Division</option>
</select>
<label for="secondOperand">Enter number 2: </label>
<input type="text" id="secondOperand" name="secondOperand" required>
<button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div>
 <c:if test="${not empty requestScope.result}">
 <p>Result: ${requestScope.result}</p>
</c:if>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: requestScope не является переменой, это префикс для доступа к req.setAttribute("result", result);
Возможная проблема здесь? Возможно я не правильно разобрался в литературе. По сути, сама проверка на наличие числа не нужна. Но нужно, "вытащить"  результат после операции и показать его . Если возможная проблема здесь, подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу ее устранить?